# 乒 and 乓 characters are together a pictographic group?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

倪阔乐 pointed in his answer, 乒 and 乓 have onomatopoeic use and these characters were "chosen for the sound playing the game makes" and it's a Great explanation but....

When I see 乒乓 together I see the picture of "table" with their legs (丿丶) plus a "net" on it. Not you ?

They looks like pictographic characters but using not one but two characters instead!

Primarily I was asking the etymology and if they have they other uses ? (this part is filled, thanks!)

Comment: 象 rattle iciba：雹子打在屋顶上乒乓乱响。jukuu：门窗被风刮得乒乓山响。

Comment: The question here is different from the title question in http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14138/are-%E4%B9%92-and-%E4%B9%93-used-in-classical-chinese but is already asked in the text of that question.  And the answer here partly conflicts with the answer there.  I think it would be better if the answers were merged and one of the questions closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

乒 and 乓 have onomatopoeic use for sudden noise from a gun or similar. Their resemblance with an actual pingpong table is coincidental, and the characters were chosen for the sound playing the game makes.

See [https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/乒乓球](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E4%B9%92%E4%B9%93%E7%90%83) for the history.

Both characters are used individually, but do not form any other words than 乒乓 and related terms. They derive from 兵 (bīng, soldier).

**Edit:** Expanding a bit, because these characters are a bit of interest. They seem to appear during Ming in the 16th century, with the vernacular literature of the time. Some examples:

西游记 / Journey to the West (Ming, 1580): 如此二三日，又听得后宰门乒乓乒乓，砖瓦乱响。

封神演义 / Creation of the gods (Ming, 1560): 乒乒乓乓，如同阵前炮响；轰轰烈烈，却似锣鼓齐鸣。

儒林外史 / Rulin waishi / Unofficial world history (Qing, 1750): 忽然乒乓一声响，屋梁上掉下一件东西来；不左不右，不上不下，端端正正掉在燕窝碗里，将碗打翻。

Some sources tell that 乒 is a hand holding a pickax, but late characters are rarely if ever ideographic in nature. More likely, some creative author used 兵 to coin a new set of onomatopoetic characters. 乒乒乓乓 has so become a proverb from the Ming era romance literature.

Comment: individual use: iciba: 乓（形容枪声、关门声、东西砸破声等）她把枪对着他，然后就是乓的一声。我们听到乓的一声枪响.乒:中国队囊括所有五枚世乒竞标赛金牌.他们用脚在桌子搞得乒零乓郎一团糟. ” 莫里哀说过